# Is there a way to search a file by its URL?

Tags: box-api

I'm trying to use the Search API and I would like to search a file by field **download_url**,
here is the API call:

https://api.box.com/2.0/search?query=https://www.box.com/shared/static/dz90ncun10l2wcsfbi3d.jpg

The return is:

```
{
    "total_count": 0,
    "entries": [],
    "limit": 30,
    "offset": 0
}
```

The file that I'm searching has shared link enable (shared_link != null) .. Am I doing something wrong or this need to be a feature request?

Thanks

Comment: img is blank, and I don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: Closing as NARQ pending further information from OP that makes this answerable.

Comment: The link is blank because you don't have the required authentication headers... This is a question for Box API developers, look the tag.

Comment: Doesn't mean I can't figure out what you're doing wrong, but I sure can't if you don't give me any info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The search API is used to search *for* files and folders, not within them. The index is built off of file name, file description, and text content of the file. Shared links are not factored into search.